# \Verb{} in fvextra: Highlighting \Verb{} text to be able to break at the end of line

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim, inline, soul, fancyvrb

Searching through various packages documentation and this site I have found how to write inline verbatim text, that is (when neccessary) broken at the end of line. For this feature, I am using `\Verb{}` command provided by package `fvextra`.
This works perfectly well, but I would like to achieve also highlighting the verbatim text, still preserving the automatic line-breaking.

With text, that doesnt require too much escaping, I am effectively using command `\texttt{}`, which is highlightable by command `\hl{}` provided by `soul` package.

Can the same effect be achived also for text with `\Verb{}` command?

MWE:

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright] {scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage [left=2.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=3cm, headheight=15.3pt] {geometry}       

\usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fvextra}
\fvinlineset{breaklines,%
   breakafter=\space ,
   breakanywhere
}

\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\sethlcolor{Snow2}

\begin{document}

Test of \Verb{\Verb{}} command working at the end of line \Verb{text that should go on as long as it is forced to be broken at the end of line}.

Test of \Verb{\texttt{}} command working at the end of line, that is also highlighted \hl{\texttt{text that should go on as long as it is forced to be broken at the end of line}}.

There is some text to make sure that argument of command \Verb{\Verb{}} will be broken  \hl{{\Verb{Text in Verb}}, but the highlighting with soul doesnt work.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fvextra`'s `\Verb{...}` can be used inside other commands, unlike `\verb` and some other verbatim commands.  When this is done, `\Verb` behaves like `\texttt`, except that it performs a lot of analysis so that almost all characters will work except for `#`, `%`, unpaired curly braces `{}`, multiple adjacent spaces, double carets `^^`, and some situations involving backslashes.  So the easiest solution for most cases is to define a new command wrapping `\Verb` and `\hl`, perhaps something like this in the preamble:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\HLVerb}[1]{%
  \edef\hverb@tmp{#1}%
  \expandafter\hl\expandafter{\hverb@tmp}}
\makeatother
```

If you need a broader range of characters than what `\Verb` can handle when wrapped in another command, you might consider using `\EscVerb` instead, which makes the backslash into an escape for non-alphanumeric ASCII characters.

Comment: Hello Mr. Poore, thank you for your answer. Your suggested `\newcommand` definition works for my MWE perfectly, but my MWE maybe wasnt constructed properly (and has been then misleading). If I put ANY TeX special character as argument of `\HLVerb` it is by TeX recognised as such (those are mostly underscores `_`) which leads to TeX failing compilation and looking for inline math ... The same happens if I use `\EscVerb` in simillar manner. I still feel as TeX beginner (regular user?), so even for educational purposes I would like to ask you what does this newcommand definition do?

Comment: I understand first two lines. In Wiki, I found that `\edef` is defining new command with expansion of next command sequence. But I cant find what is the original definition of command `\hverb@tmp{#1}` ? I will also work on understanding `\expandafter`; what I found out yet means that first is exapnded second `\expandafter` ; then `\hl{exapansion product}` is expanded too ... ? If my follow-up comments are not entirely clear, I edit my question with MWE that would display my situation more specifically.