# Printing TeX special symbols with tex.print, but also highlighted

Tags: luatex, highlighting, soul

I would like to be able to automatically print TeX special symbols into pdf. Mostly (but not only) the underscore symbol `_`, but also highlighted by grey color (similar to how it is displayed in this site).
Why: I am writing basic python and R tutorials for my colleagues. I am using pythonTeX a lot. But very often I have to write code that contains underscore. Escaping is tedious and error prone and I would like to find and automated solution.

This is a follow-up question from this one:

[\Verb{} in fvextra: Highlighting \Verb{} text to be able to break at the end of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522143/verb-in-fvextra-highlighting-verb-text-to-be-able-to-break-at-the-end-of)

Mr. Poore gave me some directions there, but as being still new to TeX, it is not entirely clear to me how to achieve my goal.

MWE:

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright] {scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage [left=2.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=3cm, headheight=15.3pt] {geometry}       

\usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fvextra}
\fvinlineset{breaklines,%
   breakafter=\space ,
   breakanywhere
}

\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\sethlcolor{Snow2}

\newcommand{\hltt}[1]{%
\hl{\texttt{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\hlttlua}[1]{%
\hl{\texttt{\directlua{tex.print(-2,"#1")}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Another option with use of \EscVerb{\\directlua} with more special symbols: \hltt{Hello W\_o\_r\#ld without percent sign}
\item Another option with use of \EscVerb{\\directlua} with more special symbols: \directlua{tex.print(-2,"Hello W_o_r#ld without percent sign")}
\item Another option with use of \EscVerb{\\directlua} with more special symbols: \texttt{\directlua{tex.print(-2,"Hello W_o_rld without percent sign")}}
\item Another option with use of \EscVerb{\\directlua} with more special symbols: \hlttlua{Hello W_o_rld without percent sign}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Explanation: Desired to make no.4 work. Right now, I am getting error:

```
unexpected symbol near '{'
```

which I dont know how to deal with (also I wasnt able to find solution in SE). Desired look in pdf is the same as is with no. 1; but without manual escaping done in the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to expand `\directlua` before `\hl` enters the scene.

```latex
\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright] {scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage [left=2.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=3cm, headheight=15.3pt] {geometry}       

\usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fvextra}
\fvinlineset{breaklines,
   breakafter=\space ,
   breakanywhere
}

\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\sethlcolor{Snow2}

\newcommand{\hltt}[1]{%
  \hl{\texttt{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\hlttlua}[1]{%
  \expanded{\noexpand\hl{\noexpand\texttt{\directlua{tex.print(-2,"#1")}}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Another option with use of \EscVerb{\\directlua} with more special symbols:
      \hltt{Hello W\_o\_r\#ld without percent sign}
\item Another option with use of \EscVerb{\\directlua} with more special symbols:
      \directlua{tex.print(-2,"Hello W_o_r#ld without percent sign")}
\item Another option with use of \EscVerb{\\directlua} with more special symbols:
      \texttt{\directlua{tex.print(-2,"Hello W_o_rld without percent sign")}}
\item Another option with use of \EscVerb{\\directlua} with more special symbols:
      \hlttlua{Hello W_o_rld without percent sign}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Topic of TeX expansion is complicated for me. I thought that expansion will be the cause of this problem. Do I understand correctly, that no expansion is done until command is read as whole? And the everything gets expanded at same time? Also, what baffles me, is the output of no.2, printing two # symbols. I think I read about it somewhere, but I cant remember the reason (Its no problem in python, since # symbol is for comments; but it got me curious)...

Comment: @TomášKruliš The main problem is that `\hl` wants to see *words*, not the instructions necessary to produce them; expanding `\directlua` before `\hl` can act is so the way to go. Why do you get two `#` symbols? Because, when TeX absorbs arguments to macros, it doubles every `#`.